# What Grammatical name and Grammatical function is given to the part of sentence in parenthesis

Tags: grammaticality

Traders (who used to come early to the market) claimed he had probably had some place he sleeps

Comment: It's a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause.

Comment: Does the original sentence you are asking about have the parentheses?

Comment: Paraphrasing: 'Traders – and in passing we could add that they used to come early to the market –  claimed that he had probably had some place to sleep.' Without the setting off of the relative clause: 'The subset of traders comprising those who used to come early to the market claimed that ....'

Answer (score 3):

Assume the original sentence is:

> Traders **who used to come early to the market** claimed he had
>   probably had some place he sleeps

Then the function of the relative clause (marked in bold) is to identify the subset of traders being talked about; namely, those who used to come early - as opposed to those who used to come later.

You can take your pick as to how you name such a relative clause:

> The *Cambridge Grammar Of English* (p566) calls it a **defining relative clause**.
>
> *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (p1034) calls it an
>   **integrated relative clause**.
>
> *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (p198) calls it a **restrictive
>   relative clause**.

Assuming, alternatively, that the original sentence sets off the relative clause with commas or parentheses,  then the function of the clause is to give extra information that applies to all traders - as opposed to other visitors to the market:

> Traders, who used to come early to the market, claimed he had
>   probably had some place he sleeps.

The three grammars listed above name such 'additional information' clauses **non-defining**, **supplementary** and **non-restrictive**, respectively.

A further point, a non-restrictive (etc.) relative clause, i.e. one that is set off by commas in writing, will normally be said a lower pitch than its restrictive equivalent.