# "I am the man, who commands you" vs. "I am the man, who command you"

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

In a [passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=OtyxwvP-Im4C&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=To+an+inattentive+reader,+the+expressions,+%E2%80%9CI+am+the+man,+who+commands+you,%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9CI+am+the+man,+who+command+you,%E2%80%9D+may+appear+to+be+precisely+equivalent.+This,+however,+is+by+no+means+the+case&source=bl&ots=bCVC92q4jl&sig=ACfU3U092qE84SfvGELHImQxkdfPx_4YAw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSn-OkrYbsAhVilFwKHQwVDTAQ6AEwAXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=To%20an%20inattentive%20reader%2C%20the%20expressions%2C%20%E2%80%9CI%20am%20the%20man%2C%20who%20commands%20you%2C%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CI%20am%20the%20man%2C%20who%20command%20you%2C%E2%80%9D%20may%20appear%20to%20be%20precisely%20equivalent.%20This%2C%20however%2C%20is%20by%20no%20means%20the%20case&f=false) I encountered:

> To an inattentive reader, the expressions,
>
> - “I am the man, who commands you”
>
> and
>
> - “I am the man, who command you”

[reformatted, EA]

> may appear to be precisely equivalent. This, however, is by no means
> the case —(See “The Etymology and Syntax of the English Language
> explained,” p. 261, fourth Edition.).

I could not find the 4th edition of the referred book, and unfortunately not sure I understand the difference here.

Comment: Three points: **1** “I am the man, who command[s] you,” does not appear to be a full sentence and is therefore meaningless - could you give a full sentence and some context? **2** The book was first published in 1836 - in the intervening 184 years much has changed. **3** "commands" is the indicative, "command" is, or appears to be, the subjunctive.

Comment: @Greybeard, **(1)** I'm afraid there is no full sentence. This was used to illustrate a point - the author seems to think this is enough. This "sentence" does convey meaning. **(2)** Maybe so. If in modern English there is no difference, it answers my question (but only partially since I do want to understand the point of the author). **(3)**: I think the subjunctive/indicative *is* indeed the point here(judging from the context) , but I cannot interpret it in terms of what difference does it make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Grammatical name and Grammatical function is given to the part of sentence in parenthesis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493920/what-grammatical-name-and-grammatical-function-is-given-to-the-part-of-sentence) / [choice of relative pronouns who and/or that for- people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174933/choice-of-relative-pronouns-who-and-or-that-for-people/174961#174961) / [comma, non-restrictive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182769/does-removing-the-comma-before-which-etc-in-a-non-restrictive-clause-change-th)

Comment: ... 'I am the man, who command you ...' is not a stand-alone sentence and if part of a subjunctive construction is archaic at best. 'I am the man, who commands you.' as a standalone sentence, with a non-defining relative clause, seems doomed to remain highly unidiomatic (though perhaps some licensing context in period fiction might be contrived).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for you suggestions, but to be honest with you, I can't see any connection between my question and those suggestions. (apart from being related to relative clause). My question is specific about usage of the "s" ("who command" vs "who command**s**")

Comment: This is an 1830 attempt to give a near word-for-word translation of a Latin text; it just doesn't work in modern English (and I'm not sure that more than a handful of scholars, and few others, would have been familiar with the attempts to mirror Latin usages in English even then).

Comment: You need to ditch the comma.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul No; this question is about the split subject (split by the predicate). I've found a rare modernish  example: 'He is here Who walked on the water' (in [Christian] song lyrics). The defining relative clause is unusually detached from the NP antecedent ('He'; 'I' in OP's example) by the predicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I selected it because you'd linked it

Comment: Yes; there's been a lot of development since then. I'd retract the CV if OP structured the actual question more clearly. d_e has thrown some light on this. The second sentence (if it actually is acceptable) is of a form I don't think has been addressed here before, and I'm having difficulty finding analysis of.

Answer (score 0):

> To an inattentive reader, the expressions, “I am the man, who commands you,” and “I am the man, who command you,” may appear to be precisely equivalent.

This is obsolete English grammar - the comma is no longer inserted.

Full sentences might read

“I am the man who commands you [to attack the enemy.]” - One of my jobs is to tell you to attack the enemy. (Note that the object is "you.")

“I am the man who command (subjunctive) that you attack the enemy.” - I am the one who is currently ordering you to attack the enemy. (Note that the object is a content clause - "that you attack the enemy")

Comment: What does "attack then enemy" mean?

Comment: No; d_e has found an authoritative analysis positing a split subject.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You may have misunderstood when you wrote: *No; d_e has found an authoritative analysis positing a split subject.* The origin has absolutely no bearing on the question which is *"My question is specific about usage of the "s" ("who command" vs "who commands")* (see d_e's comment above and to which you responded.

Comment: Without the commas, as in the version d_e has found:  'I am the man who commands you' {using unremarkable defining/restrictive relative clause, antecedent '[the] man'} v 'I am the man who command you' ↔ 'I who command you am the man'. {The unrearranged original  shows the predicate splitting the subject _I who command you_, placing the defining relative clause (antecedent again 'the man')  of the subject after predicate _am the man_. Probably unacceptable nowadays, but never any subjunctive involved.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah! So the writer was explaining/attempting to explain "I who am..." and "I who is..."

Answer (score 0):

I found the [source, Crombie](https://archive.org/details/etymologysyntaxo00crom/page/204/mode/2up) (p.204-205 Note 3 in *The Etymology and Syntax of the English Language explained* (4th ed)):

> Note 3. — In the earlier editions of Murray's Grammar,
> we find the following rule : " When the relative is preceded by two nominatives of different persons, it may agree in person with either, as, ' I am the man who commands
> you,' or 'I am the man who command you.'" The rule
> here given is erroneous.

> The construction is by no means
> arbitrary. If we say, " I am the man who commands
> you," the relative clause, with the antecedent man, form
> the predicate ; and the sentence is equivalent to " I am
> your commander." If we say, " I am the man who command you," the man simply is the predicate, and I who command you the subject ; thus, " I who command you,"
> or " I your commander am the man.

Comment: What happened to the commas? (Which quote is accurate?) // Can you think of an example (where the predicate splits the single subject) which sounds idiomatic nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong then all the way. This is one of those things that I thought English has lost in time (like gender and most of differences of number and person in verb conjugation).
I had not considered:
" In relative clauses, **who** (like other relative pronouns) takes the number (singular or plural) of its antecedent. **Who** also takes the person (first, second or third) of its antecedent." (Theodore M. Bernstein, *The careful writer/ A modern guide to English usage*)
In which case, the sentences are not only correct, but might indicate differences in matter of 'emphasis':

1. I am the man, who command you .... = 'I am that man' is more important.
2. I am the man who command you... = 'I am your commander' is more important.
   Even though what I had written on Latin is correct, it was quite wrong in what I said about English, so I have rewritten my answer. Thank you all who commented otherwise, helping me to see the point.

Comment: Your (1) and (2) are identical. An answer will address the acceptability (over time) of a sentence where a subject containing a relative clause ('who command you' here) is split, the relative clause being postposed to a position after the predicate ('am the man). I've found one further example: 'He is here Who walked on the water' (in [Christian] song lyrics). But this contains a locative complement.